# How to rewrite my JavaScript Language Switcher code so that I can still switch languages manually

Tags: javascript, hubspot

I am using HubSpot to build my website which contains multi-language variants on some pages. The default pages are written in UK English while the variants are written in US English. The default URLs generate like this: **https://example.com/blog/example-post** while the US URLS generate like this: **https://example.com/en-us/blog/example-post**

Currently I have implemented the following JavaScript code that shows the user the correct URL based on their browser language settings. So when the browser language settings are set to "English-United States" this URL generates: **https://example.com/en-us/blog/example-post**, and when the browser language settings are set to anything else this URL generates: https://example.com/blog/example-post

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  // set a HubL variable to pull in languages of available translated pages
  {% set languages = content.translated_content.values()|selectattr('published')|map('language') %}
  // append the current page's language to our languages HubL variable
  {% do languages.append(content.language) %}

  // add toLowerCase to userLang because some browsers use capitals and JavaScript is case sensitive
  const userLang = (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage).toLowerCase();
  // set our languages HubL variable as our supportedLanguages
  const supportedLanguages = {{ languages|tojson }};
  // set our default language
  const defaultLanguage = "en";
  // get current path
  let path = window.location.pathname;

  // Check if the userLang is "en-GB" and set it to "en" (default language) if true
  if (userLang === "en-gb") {
    userLang = defaultLanguage;
  }

  // get first path (where the language is usually set)
  let pathFirstString = path.split('/')[1];

  // check if first path matches one of our supported languages
  // if it does, update the path variable to remove the first path
  if (supportedLanguages.indexOf(pathFirstString) !== -1) {
    path = '/' + path.split('/').slice(2).join('/');
  }

  // If userLang is not in supported languages
  if (supportedLanguages.indexOf(userLang) === -1) {
    // and current path does not equal default path
    // go to default URL
    if (path !== window.location.pathname) {
      window.location.href = window.location.origin + path;
    }
  // else if our language path does not match the userLang
  } else if (pathFirstString !== userLang) {
     // if userLang does not equal the defaultLanguage, go to userLang URL
     if (userLang !== defaultLanguage) {
       window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/' + userLang + path;
     // else if user is not currently on the default page, go to the default page
     } else if (path !== window.location.pathname) {
       window.location.href = window.location.origin + path;
     }
  }
</script>
```

The problem is that I also have a language switcher module on the site. So when I manually click on the language switcher icon to switch to either the UK or US version of the page the code overrides this action and keeps it at the URL that it was told to generate based on the browser language settings.

How can I fix this?

I would like users to be redirected to the correct page based on their browser language settings, however I would also like them to have the option to switch the language themselves.